# PostgreSQL IF value doesn't exist THEN INSERT value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I've tried multiple variations of this code and it keeps giving me the SQL state: 42601 error. I've looked at the docs and tried using their examples which sometimes work, but do not do what I want.

```
IF (SELECT guildid FROM Servers <> 1) THEN
  INSERT INTO Servers (guildid) VALUES (1)
END IF;
```

My Servers table is simple. I just have a single row called guildid. I do not want a CASE statement because that only outputs messages.

Comment: `CASE` expressions (not "statements") don't "output messages".

Comment: You probably have a `column` called *guildid*. `Rows` don't have names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to worry about race conditions (which the `if` approach suggests), then:

```
INSERT INTO Servers (guildid)
   SELECT guildid
   FROM (VALUES (1)) v(guildid)
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Servers s WHERE s.guildid = v.guildid);
```

To protect the table, I would suggest adding a unique index on it.  In fact, just declare `guildid` to be the primary key.  In that case, your original insert will simply fail, if you attempt to insert a duplicate value.

Comment: How would I be able to insert a different value into a separate row every time the value doesn’t exist? (so that would be two values in two different rows)

Comment: @SethDeegan . . . New questions should be asked as questions, not in comments.

Comment: Could you explain how the `FROM (VALUES (1)) v(guildid)`? 
I know that after a FROM, there should be the column name. This looks like a placeholder system but I can’t find any documentation on it. Could you please explain the query and provide a documentation source?

Comment: `v` is a table alias.  `guildid` names the column in the table:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-values.html.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unique constraint on that column, you can use `on conflict do nothing`:

```
INSERT INTO Servers (guildid) VALUES (1)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```